# __Construct within OOP Classes?

Tags: php, oop

I am newish to the OOP style of PHP5, I have noticed `__construct` and `__deconstruct` within example classes and production classes.

I have read over the manual of this:

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

and looked over a range of questions/answers on StackOverflow. I'm still having trouble to understand what is the actual meaning of its exisitance?

```
class foo {
   function __construct()
   {
     // do something 
   }

   public function Example ()
   {
    echo "Example Functions";
   }

   function __destruct()
   {
     // do something
   }
}
```

The same class can function the same with no hits as:

```
class foo {
       public function Example ()
       {
        echo "Example Functions";
       }
    }
```

But the manual states with the above example, that my first function will take over the role as the `__construct`

Why is this a priority within PHP5 OOP Classes?

Comment: How well do you know OOP? PHP is not an ideal language to learn / practice OOP-style programming on, as it permits all sorts of weird things. For example, you can call `foo::Example();` via static context, even though the "proper" way to call is `$myFoo = new foo(); $myFoo->Example();`. Calling it the latter way will bypass your constructors/destructors entirely, as you're invoking without instantiating.

Comment: @Lübnah  If PHP is not an ideal method to practice OOP style, then what do you suggest?

Comment: As much as I dislike Java, it's a great language to learn the basics on. But really, any typed language will do. You want to learn the ropes with a strict language so you can at least learn to recognize the "weird voodoo" that languages like PHP will let you get away with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Foo {
    public function __construct() {
        print("This is called when a new object is created");
        // Good to use when you need to set initial values,
        // (possibly) create a connection to a database or such.
    }

    public function __destruct() {
        print("This is called when the class is removed from memory.");
        // Should be used to clean up after yourself, close connections and such.
    }
}

$foo = new Foo();
```

**Addition,**

```
class Person {

    private $name; // Instance variable
    private $status; // Instance variable

    // This will be called when a new instance of this class i created (constructed)
    public function __construct($name, $age) {
        $this->name = ucfirst($name); // Change input to first letter uppercase.

        // Let the user of our class input something he is familiar with,
        // then let the constructor take care of that data in order to fit
        // our specific needs.
        if ($age < 20) {
            $this->status = 'Young';
        } else {
            $this->status = 'Old';
        }
    }

    public function printName() {
        print($this->name);
    }

    public function printStatus() {
        print($this->status);
    }
}

$Alice = new Person('alice', 27);
$Alice->printName();
$Alice->printStatus();
```

**/Addition**

If you run the above code and read the comments you should be able to understand when and how constructors and destructors should be used.

Comment: So basically the same as `register_shutdown_function`? When the object is called, construct will run; but what should this normally contain? The parameters? the variables? what does it actually construct? I understand what they do, but what is the point of its existance?

Comment: @Codeius Error on your print within __destruct. Missing Semi-Colon

Comment: @user2146021 The additional example of a Person class should clarify the use of constructors a little, destructors are a little harder to explain with a simple example since they are usually used to close connections to resources such as databases or clean up memory that is no longer needed.

Answer (score 1):

__deconstruct

A destructor is invoked when a class is about to be garbage collected, it allows you to perform last minute operations, before the class is disposed.

A _contructor is just the opposition. It allows you to set properties to your object during its creation.

This was the old way of creating a constructor, which according to the documentation was left there for backward compatibility.

```
public function Example ()
{
  echo "Example Functions";
}
```

"For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5 cannot find a __construct() function for a given class, and the class did not inherit one from a parent class, it will search for the old-style constructor function, by the name of the class. Effectively, it means that the only case that would have compatibility issues is if the class had a method named __construct() which was used for different semantics."

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php

Comment: This answers the reason for destruct, but why is both construct and destruct preferred within a Class? What is it for? What exact roles does it perform?

Comment: Giving an example, say you have an object (Account) with the following operation: Withdraw(amount), a contructor would be useful in this example as you want to set the balance of the account before you allow money to be taken off.

Comment: In relation to "register_shutdown_function", you have to realize that PHP was not a OOP language from the start so before PHP had object it could not have destructors. That function is run when a script is finished, which is different from a class being garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to realize that a class defines a *type*, meaning both a kind of data and the operations that can be performed on that data.  That data is stored internally as member variables.  Similarly, those operations are defined by a class' methods.  A constructor is used to initialize an object's initial internal state (that is, its member variables and any internal operations).

Destructors in PHP are generally used for manual object cleanup.  They're not used all that often due to PHP's fire-and-forget nature.  They might be used to free up resources (db connections, file handles) in long running scripts.